# Trying to identify all rows that are duplicates for dates, grouped by ID (want to count for the first and any subsequent instance as a duplicate) R

Tags: r, duplicates

I a trying to create a column to label duplicate dates by ID. I only want a date to show as duplicated if it repeats for the same PAT_ID. Additionally, I want to count all instances of a duplicate date as a duplicate (rather than not counting the first instance as a duplicate). I have used this code in the past for such situations and it worked then. But it is not working now and I can't figure out why.

Here is my data:

```
c_petidesub_diab<-structure(list(PAT_ID = c(20509541L, 20996088L, 15699150L, 
9061383L, 
16105496L, 13781737L, 12814869L, 20723151L, 20451977L, 14145056L, 
14145056L, 14145056L, 19499987L, 19499987L, 19499987L, 19499987L, 
10206803L, 20935200L, 20205934L, 6471890L, 7312838L, 8705568L, 
12792099L, 19095082L, 19095082L, 19095082L, 20243600L, 20243600L, 
8285991L, 9175530L, 9175530L, 17169731L, 20793996L, 8892630L, 
8892630L, 12068391L, 5470224L, 21430152L, 6305585L, 6305585L), 
RESULT_TIME = structure(c(16386, 17200, 16931, 18500, 15453, 
16142, 17277, 17719, 17245, 16678, 16861, 18451, 15931, 15821, 
15861, 15793, 17634, 17141, 17769, 16659, 17611, 17964, 17709, 
16134, 16092, 16128, 15540, 18429, 16707, 15085, 15336, 18444, 
18548, 17452, 17452, 17961, 16149, 18121, 16408, 16427), class = "Date")), 
row.names = c(471L, 
1267L, 1880L, 3893L, 6410L, 7943L, 7979L, 9488L, 10163L, 11160L, 
11161L, 11162L, 11691L, 11692L, 11693L, 11694L, 11703L, 15464L, 
16526L, 17039L, 18436L, 19671L, 19946L, 20163L, 20164L, 20165L, 
20948L, 20949L, 22316L, 22411L, 22412L, 23885L, 24765L, 26629L, 
26630L, 26959L, 28229L, 32082L, 33923L, 33924L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my syntax:

```
c_peptide<-as.data.table(c_petidesub_diab)[, dup_c_peptide := 
(duplicated(c_petidesub_diab$RESULT_TIME))| 
(duplicated(c_petidesub_diab$RESULT_TIME, fromLast=TRUE)), by 
= c_petidesub_diab$PAT_ID][]
```

It produces this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(as.data.table(c_petidesub_diab), , `:=`(dup_c_peptide,  : 
Supplied 40 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 1 in column 'dup_c_peptide'. 
The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length 
exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this 
intent clear to readers of your code.
```

What I want is for it to show, as an example, that PAT_ID 8892630 is duplicated because the date repeats for that ID. I want both dates to show as duplicates. And I want a new column that shows this. I have used this syntax in the past and it worked. But it is not working now.

Comment: Try `as.data.table(c_petidesub_diab)[, dup_c_peptide := duplicated(RESULT_TIME) | duplicated(RESULT_TIME, fromLast=T), by = PAT_ID]`. Using `$` makes these a vector which is not expected.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use package dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
c_petidesub_diab %>% 
  mutate(duplicate = n() > 1, .by = c(PAT_ID, RESULT_TIME))
```

look for every PAT_ID / RESULT_TIME combination, when there is more than one record per group, then mark theses records as duplicate = TRUE.